# Azure Websites DNS

Tags: azure, dns, azure-web-app-service, cname

I have an azure website at yis3.azurewebsites.net - I have promoted this to be a "shared" site so that I can use a custom domain. I have the domain yorkshireimagescanning.co.uk that I bought from 123-reg.co.uk. I have configured this to give a CName record with dnsname of "awverify" and destination of awverify.yis3.azurewebsites.net.

I've waited over 12 hours and checked on digwebinterface.com and all looks good but when I click to "Manage custom domains" from the Azure portal , I enter a domain name of "yorkshireimagescanning.co.uk" but it won't accept it.

Please help

*** Edit ***
I've now waited a couple of days for domain propagation. Here's a screen grab from my domain registrar:

[image]

In the azure portal I've tried to add the following custom domains for the yis3.azurewebsites.net site but it won't accept any:

- awverify.www.yorkshireimagescanning.co.uk
  www.yorkshireimagescanning.co.uk yorkshireimagescanning.co.uk
  awverify.yorkshireimagescanning.co.uk

Here's a screen grab from the portal:

[image]

Comment: Because the site is live I've had to setup 301 web forwarding from within the 123-reg control panel until I get to the bottom of the DNS problem. I hope this doesn't confuse matters even more!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out what was wrong. I was deploying a new version of an existing site but the old version still had www.yorkshireimagescanning.co.uk set on the custom domains page. Once I deleted it then I was able to add the domain on the new azure site.

Answer (score 4):

### To use yorkshireimagescanning.co.uk

To use your domain without the www. prefix you need to add an A Record in addition to the CNAME you've added for "awverify".

First, make sure you've added the domain to the Azure portal by following the instructions under "Set the domain name in management portal" [here](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-custom-domain-name/).

Next, follow the instructions under "Configure an A record for the domain name" on [the same page](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-custom-domain-name/). This involves pointing your domain directly at the IP address of the Azure web site. You should then have added 2 DNS records in total:

```
CNAME    awverify.www     awverify.yis3.azurewebsites.net
A        xx.xx.xx.xx      (your website's IP address)
```

I've marked the next option as "preferred" because it points your domain at the Azure hostname "yis3.azurewebsites.net" instead of directly at the IP address. The IP address of your Azure website won't change, but if you ever need to deploy your website elsewhere it will have a different IP, so there will be a delay while the DNS change propagates.

---

### To use www.yorkshireimagescanning.co.uk (preferred)

To use your domain with a www. prefix you need to add another CNAME record in addition to the one you've already added.

First, make sure you've added the domain to the Azure portal by following the instructions under "Set the domain name in management portal" [here](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-custom-domain-name/).

Next, follow the instructions under "Configure the CNAME on your domain registrar" on [the same page](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-custom-domain-name/). This involves adding a CNAME that points "www" to your Azure website's hostname (yis3.azurewebsites.net). You should then have added 2 DNS records in total:

```
CNAME    awverify.www     awverify.yis3.azurewebsites.net
CNAME    www              yis3.azurewebsites.net
```

---

**A note about domain forwarding**: Don't use 301 forwarding unless your site has been permanently moved. Use 302 for temporary redirection. [More details here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_redirection#HTTP_status_codes_3xx).

Comment: Thanks for your help Greg. If go down the route of CName without an A record then I guess this means entering yorkshireimagescanning.co.uk would give a 404 to a user? This was why I'm trying to create an A record - although I realise I first need a cname for awverify and I'm failing on this early step

Comment: You can add *both* a CNAME and A record, where the A record points at the IP address of your Azure website and then your site is configured to do a 301 redirect to the www. subdomain. Or you can use your DNS provider's forwarding feature to do a 301 redirect to your www. subdomain. In these cases 301 is suitable because your site is going to stay at the www. subdomain. Have you added the domain to the portal?

Comment: Just updated my answer, after re-reading that page I linked to it seems the CNAME needs to be `awverify.www`, regardless of whether you're using a CNAME or A record.